# Injecting activateRoute class in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I am refreing to the Book(pro-Angular-6) and I came across These Syntax

```
 constructor(private model:Model,activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute) {}
```

i am confused  with the Following points

1. How can we use class Without injecting  `(what is difference between  private activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute and activateRoute:ActivatedRoute)`
2. if we can just use as reference Type  and limit the use of it inside the constructor , if it is fine i tried with the custom class inside my component i am getting  `null injection error`

   ```
      class Emp {
               name='Bob'
               id = '12'  
             }

   constructor(private model:Model,activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute,emp:Emp){}
   ```

3. Why i am able to access activated  only in the constructor if i Try to access in the Method i am getting error

   ```
   constructor(activateRoute:ActivatedRoute){
      console.log(activatedRoute)  //no error
    }

    someMethod() {
    console.log(activatedRoute)   //error Did You mean ActivatedRoute
    console.log(this.activatedRoute)  //error proprtey activateRoute Does not exist
   ```

   }

4)Moreover i am confused whether i am  defining the type or injecting in the constructor with  the following syntax `constructor(activateRoute:ActivatedRoute){}`

Answer (score 1):

1. Public dependencies can be accessed by the component's template where as **Private dependencies can't be accessed by component templates**.

Ex:

```
constructor(activateRoute:ActivatedRoute){}
```

or

```
constructor(public activateRoute:ActivatedRoute){}
```

will **not throw error** while using in template as below

```
<div *ngIf="activateRoute">content goes here </div>
```

2. In angular, we can **inject** only when a class is annotated with the **injectable** as below.

Ex:

```
    @injectable({
    providedIn:'root'
    })
     class Emp {
                name='Bob'
                id = '12'  
              }
    

export class AppComponent{
    constructor(private model:Model,activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute,emp:Emp){}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation i have added 3 point can you clarify that  after reading   if injection as public is same as without public why i am unable to acess  inside the method

Answer (score 1):

Your first question is about typescript. If you didn't specify access modifier on constructor parameters, it can be accessed only within constructor.

Answer (score 0):

First 2 above explanations are justified

3. I am  not able to access any Where except in constructor , because in constructor i passed  `activateRoute:ActivatedRoute`  as signature to constructor so i can acess only in the constructor

4 .we are refereeing to the Type  (go confused with java script object Notation)